# Create Lion DVD from Lion USB flash drive

Tags: macos

Is it possible to convert a lion Dvd from a Lion flash drive? Last year when Lion came out I created a lion install usb. I need to create a dvd to send to someone off site and did not want to give my trusty usb drive away. Is it possible to burn this to disc? I did a little googling there doesnt seem to be an easy way other than redownloading from Apple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to accomplish this by doing the following:

- Open **Disk Utility**
- Plug in your Lion Installer USB flash drive, wait for the volume to mount
- Insert a **blank DVD**
- Click on the Lion Installer volume
- Click the **Burn** button:
  [image]

This *should* burn the volume to the DVD. If it doesn't, you may have another problem at hand.